# How to coordinate randomly chosen objects in a DRF APIView?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am building an API for a game and need to select a random game round for a randomly chosen resource.

Choosing the random resource works. What I am trying to do now, in order to coordinate players is to filter the game rounds by the resource that has been chosen randomly and then return a random game round.

The code below shows what I have tried so far, namely to access the resource for which a game round has been played over the method with the @property decorator.

**models.py**

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    hash_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    creators = models.ManyToManyField(Creator)
    titles = models.ManyToManyField(Title)
    created_start = models.DateField(null=True)
    created_end = models.DateField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    institution_source = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, null=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='picture')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hash_id or ''

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.taggings.values('tag').annotate(count=Count('tag'))

        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language', 'count')


class Gameround(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gamesession = models.ForeignKey(Gamesession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def create(self):
        pass

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.taggings.values('tag')

        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language', 'resource_id')

class Tagging(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    origin = models.URLField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def create(self, tag):
        tagging = self.create(tag=tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag) or ''

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am then serialising the game round like this:

***serializers.py**

```
class GameroundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  gamesession = GamesessionSerializer(read_only=True)
  user = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
  tags_to_compare = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tags_to_compare')

  class Meta:
    model = Gameround
    fields = ['id', 'user', 'gamesession', 'created', 'score', 'tags_to_compare']

  def get_tags_to_compare(self, round):
    taggings = round.tags
    return taggings

  def to_representation(self, data):
    data = super().to_representation(data)
    return data
```

In the view I have a get request which first chooses a random resource, then I am trying to filter the game rounds to only include the ones where this resource was involved and then I am trying to retrieve a random game round.

***views.py***

```
class GameroundView(APIView):
    """
    API endpoint for game rounds
    """

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        controller = GameViewController()
        random_resource = controller.get_resource()
        gameround = Gameround.objects.all().filter(taggings__resource_id=random_resource).order_by("?").first()
        gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)
        return Response(gameround_serializer.data)
```

This does not seem to be working since I keep getting the error "The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over."

I have also tried creating an id variable and passing it on as the resource_id like this:

```
# id of the random Resource for the game round
random_resource_id = random_resource.get(random_resource.id)
gameround = Gameround.objects.all().filter(taggings__resource_id=random_resource_id).order_by("?").first()
```

This leads to the 'Response' object has no attribute 'id' error when I reload the page in the browser.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Below also the **Gameviewcontroller** that is inside the **views.py** file

```
class GameViewController:

        def get_random_object(self, MyModel):
        random_object = None
        object_count = MyModel.objects.all().count() + 1
        while not MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=random_object).exists():
            for obj in range(object_count):
                n = random.randint(1, object_count)
                if MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=n).exists():
                    random_object = n
                    return random_object

def get_random_id(self, MyModel):
        """Method for large querysets"""
        random_object = None
        object_count = MyModel.objects.all().count() + 1
        for obj in range(object_count):
            n = random.randint(1, object_count)
            while not MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=n).exists():
                alt = random.randint(1, object_count)
                if MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=alt).exists():
                    random_object = n

        return random_object

    def get_resource(self):
        random_resource_id = self.get_random_object(Resource)
        current_resource = Resource.objects.all().filter(id=random_resource_id)
        resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(current_resource, many=True)
        data = {'resource': resource_serializer.data}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def get_gameround_matching_resource(self, random_resource):
        """Checks if a previously played game round exists for a randomly chosen resource"""
        current_gameround = Gameround.objects.all().filter(ressource__in=random_resource).order_by('?').first()

        if current_gameround.exists():
            gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(current_gameround)
            data = {'gameround': gameround_serializer.data}
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def timer(self, start):
        """Start a new timer as soon as a gameround has been selected"""
        start_time = start
        elapsed_time = None
        if start_time is not None:
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
        """Stop the timer, and return the elapsed time"""
        if start_time is None:
            elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
        return elapsed_time

    def get_gamesession(self):
        """Retrieves a randomly chosen gamesession object"""
        current_gamesession = Gamesession.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        gamesession_serializer = GamesessionSerializer(current_gamesession)
        data = {'gameround': gamesession_serializer.data}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Update question with `GameViewController` view

Comment: @Ahtisham, I have updated it now.

Comment: Where is `get_random_object` defined in `GameViewController` ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I have added it now. Sorry I missed that one.

Comment: In `get_random_object` the variable `random_object` you set as `None` how is that going to work when you use it in query. `MyModel.objects.all().filter(id=random_object).exists()` i don't think that is going to work.

Comment: I am then assigning it in the loop. I tested it and it works - it always returns a random resource object in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it by rewriting the get request like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
    resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(random_resource)  # Response is a serialized JSON object
    random_resource_id = random_resource.id   # id of the random Resource for the game round
    gameround = Gameround.objects.all().filter(taggings__resource_id=random_resource_id).order_by("?").first()
    gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)

    return Response({
        'resource to coordinate': resource_serializer.data,
        'gameround': gameround_serializer.data,
    })
```